# How to write C# case insensitive LIKE statement for SQLIte using ICU extension?

Tags: c#, sqlite, icu

SQLite has [limitation](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18) on using LIKE for non-ASCII symbols. ICU extension [solves](http://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/icu/README.txt) this problem.
How to write code in C# for creating following case insensitive statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE surname LIKE '%Пупкин%'
```

P.S. If there is another solution for using in C# LIKE statement for non-ASCII symbols please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<Persons> p = persons.Where(x => x.surname.Contains("Пупкин"));
```

will produce

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE surname LIKE '%Пупкин%'
```

You don't need an additional parameter as the produced LIKE-statement is already case insensitive, automatically.

While `IndexOf()` is a good idea, it is not supported on LINQ2SQL. 
LINQ2SQL does not support any way to provide a `CultureInfo` and I'm not sure the SQLite Server compares `InvariantCulture` or `Ordinal`.

**EDIT:** When you setup the [EntityFramework with SQLite](http://bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html) (I suggest you). You can retrieve the data like so:

```
string searchTerm = "Пупкин";
using (MyDatabaseContext context = new MyDatabaseContext())
{
    IEnumerable<Persons> p = context.Persons.Where(x => x.surname.Contains(searchTerm));
}
```

Comment: You gave a solution for manipulating data which is already retreived from DB. But I'm asking about SQLite request.

Comment: The easiest would be you get familiar with the EntityFramework. [Here](http://bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html) you can see how to use it with SQLite. Then you simply use the `Where` method on the persons collection object in the EF context object. When doing so, it will produce the SQL statement and execute it on the connection object that is maintained by the context object.

Comment: Could you please provide a more precise solution of how to use case insensitive LIKE in EntityFramework?

Comment: `LIKE` is always case insensitive in SQL. When you use Linq2Sql you can perform the `Contains()` method and it will produce the statement and execute it once you access any object from the result collection. You can even drop the EntityFramework idea and use a [SQLiteDbConnection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application) object and perform a raw SQL statement that looks like the statement you desire. As I understand the extension help document, it replaces the general LIKE, so the statement stays the same. Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this alternative, may be will help you:

```
 _database.Table<People>.Where(c => c.surname.ToUpper().Contains("Пупкин".ToUpper())  )
```

Please try and give us a feedback, if it is working or not.

Answer (score -1):

C# code

```
var lst = (From p In persons
            Where p.surname.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
            Select p).ToList()
```

[InvariantCultureIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) is one of the options of [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. This might help you to achieve  C# LIKE

Comment: As I remember, LINQ already creates case insensitive comparison when using String.Compare without additional parameters, they don't?

Comment: Yes, String.Compare can be used as LINQ and third parameter Ignorcase helps to create case insensitive comparison, for example String.Compare(p.surname, searchText, True) = 0 . This helps to find exact match. Previously, It was a typo, just edit the answer. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: That's not what I meant exactly. However, after a bit research I found out it was `Contains` that does not require an additional parameter to be case insensitive.

Comment: It's not the question how to sort/compare data within C#. My topic is how to retreive case insensitive data from SQLite DB using LIKE statement?

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = people.Where(x=> x.Surname.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
```

Comment: This expression searching case insensitive text within 'people' variable. I need to search case insensitive text within SQLite database.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination.